# security policy diference: fs.link() vs mklink /h

Tags: node.js, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, hardlink

**UPDATED:**

On a windows 2008R2 server (where we have admin priveges, but are not running elevated) I am able to manually use the console command

```
> mklink /h < link> <target>
```

to create hard links between files on a single volume.

However, in node.js (which we need to work) which I run from the same command line and as the same user. I am using the fs.link() command and it is getting an security violation.

However, this problem does not exist on a Windows 7 computer that I have. There I can do the fs.link() and it creates the hard link. So it looks like a security policy issues. What should I be looking for?

Comment: I would guess that `fs.link()` attempts to generate a symbolic link, rather than a hard link.

Comment: I have a windows 7 box, and Fs.link creates a hard link in win7

Comment: Try using Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to see what exactly node.js is trying to do and in what context.  Compare to mklink.